# Error: "something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item" on only some subsections (\subsection*{abcd}). also getting an error at only one \end{quote}

Tags: errors

Absolutely nothing was wrong with my document until I decided to work on it today. Now it's giving me random error messages, and it's messing up the formatting on exactly one of my subsections. I've never heard of or used a "\item" so I'm not sure what that's supposed to mean. It's literally just linear algebra homework, it's nothing fancy and I've never had this problem before.

I'm being told I shouldn't have links but I wasn't sure how to show what the issue is. I've attached images of what I'm referring to instead.

[image: image of the code where some of the errors are]

[image: another image of where I'm getting errors here]

I have similar if not identical formatting for every other question but I'm only getting these errors on question 4 for some reason. I'm just going to keep the link [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/kgpzmbcsbvry) in case anyone wants to actually look at the document.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained.

Comment: do not use external links but as your first error message shows the error is from a spurious `\\ ` on line 295 that you should delete

Comment: "Now it's giving me random error messages" latex mesages may not always be clear, but they are never random

Comment: @DavidCarlisle even when it's removed there's still an error

Comment: Please delete this screenshot and replace it by your code. Thank you

Comment: make a small complete document that shows the error and add to your question. do not use external links to projects that will change

Comment: do not have `\subsection` inside `quote`, and do not use `\\ ` at the ends of paragraphs

Comment: @DavidCarlisle taking the `\subsection` out of the `quote` fixed it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I looked at your overleaf project this time as you are new to the site, but please in future make an example here